# Do you ever get to practice ejecting out of a plane as a fighter pilot?

Tags: military, fighter, ejection-seat

The military throws away **a lot** of equipment simply because it doesn't hold up to current standards. So I was wondering the following.

As a fighter pilot, would you ever get a practice run ejecting out of a plane, or is it just kind of one of those things you read about and hope you never have to do it? What is it like ejecting out of a plane at 500 knots? 1000?

Comment: I have no idea how accurate [this article is](http://www.smh.com.au/executive-style/culture/how-dangerous-is-it-to-eject-from-a-fighter-jet-20120731-23c2g.html), but if it is even roughly accurate, it suggests that serious injuries are not uncommon, which implies that it is not one of those things that are tested all the way through.

Comment: I'd wager a real ejection is definitely one of those things a pilot hopes to never have to do - While being blasted clear of an aircraft that's about to explode or crash is preferable to the alternative (dying) it's certainly not without its own risks.

Comment: I remember hearing that one of the pieces of advice given to those who may have to eject is to be sure and put your back in the position you would like it to be for the rest of your life.

Comment: If you are in a situation where you have to eject, you aren't expecting to come out without injuries.

Comment: Can't they just back flip the seat, so that the pilot does not have to face the acceleration in Mach 1 cases? Would that help?

Comment: @Firee No. The problem isn't that the pilot is suddenly exposed to high-speed winds in their face. The problem is that it is necessary to accelerate the seat vertically extremely hard to avoid the seat being struck by the rest of the plane.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Air forces use special training rigs rather than real ejection seats. [Example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riKkQ2GqZwA)

[image]

Plenty of pilots have survived ejection (Wikipedia says "As of 20 June 2011 ... the number of lives saved by Martin-Baker products was 7,402 from 93 air forces")

The types of injury are illustrated by [this example](http://emj.bmj.com/content/17/5/371.full)

> The ejection seat has been responsible for saving the lives of thousands of pilots around the world since its introduction in the late 1940s. Typical survival rates quoted in the literature vary from 80–97%.
>
> It is generally accepted that radiographic evidence of vertebral fracture can be found in 30%–70% of aircrew after ejection

The reason real ejection seats are not used is almost certainly the high risk of injury. Ejecting clear from a high speed jet requires a lot of acceleration.

Comment: Just a couple things to think about.  The parachutes used aren't anything like what your skydive with.  You come crashing back to earth around 30mph.  Broken legs and ankles are very common. Flail injuries are all but guaranteed during a high speed ejection.

Comment: Cons: broken ribs, broken ankles. Pros: not exploding in a jet fueled inferno.

Answer (score 21):

Ejecting at 1000 knots means ejection into supersonic flow. Not even the [Zvezda K-36](http://www.zvezda-npp.ru/engl/k36-d.html), the indisputably best ejection seat around, is rated for that. For this kind of speed, [whole enclosures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_crew_capsule) have been designed which did not work all too well when they had to be used.

[image: Ejection seat test rig in action]

For training, there are [simulators](http://www.etcaircrewtraining.com/ejectionseat/) to prepare pilots for that hopefully rare occurrence (the picture above is from this link; there you'll find more pics and a list of their customers), but mostly, [simulations](http://www.ansys-blog.com/aircraft-ejection-seats/) are run with simulated pilots, too. The spinal loads are too high to have pilots exposed to them regularly without the benefits which go with a successful ejection.

For the things that might happen, see what [William Rankin went through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rankin) on July 26, 1959. It can last quite a while, too. In his case 40 minutes.

By the way, ejection seats started to save pilot's lives in 1942 (Germany) and 1945 [(Sweden)](http://u-fr.blogspot.de/2011/01/early-swedish-ejection-seats.html#more).

Comment: On the other hand, the SR-71 used an ejection seat instead of a capsule. The crew wore full pressure suits, though, which provided similar benefits (one test pilot had his aircraft break up on him [he didn't eject, and was unconscious when he left the plane], and [survived](http://www.barthworks.com/aviation/sr71breakup.htm))

Answer (score 12):

[I particularly like this site](http://www.ejectionsite.com/)

> What is it like ejecting out of a plane at 500 knots? 1000?

Look for this story on the linked site... A USAF F-15 crew ejected, at night, estimated well over mach 1. The back seater was killed in the ejection; the pilot survived; wreaked havoc on his musculoskeletal system and required the lower part of one leg to be amputated but eventually returned to flying status.

> As a fighter pilot, would you ever get a practice run ejecting out of a plane

My experience in a ejection trainer, much like the "air force training rig" above, gave a very short initial jolt equivalent to the real thing. I had my head bent ever so slightly and I had a sore neck for weeks. There was never a repeat ride in our year long training.

Ejecting out of the real thing for training? We would have called that sort of thing "practice bleeding".

Comment: An SR-71 pilot survived an ejection during a mid-air breakup at 2000mph

Answer (score 8):

There are ejection seat trainers, most concentrate of the required procedure *before* ejection and upon successful completion do a short 10 cm hitch upward, only a jolt to indicate end of procedure.

[image]

Some air forces do have trainers that give more of a ride. I got a demo ride in the sim in the picture, since I was involved in supplying some of the hardware. It was a severely toned down ride with much lower accelerations than pilots experience for real, but still too much for my blood pressure: one moment I was giving the all clear to the instructor, the next moment I was 3 metres in the air with an aching neck. I have no recollection of what happened in between.